# How do I make a button execute code only if text is entered in a field?

Tags: android

I'm making an app for Android, and if you click the calculate button on one of the pages, without anything entered in the text boxes, it force closes. Some users were wondering if this could be fixed, so I was wondering if there was a way to make the `onClickListener` execute only if there is something inside the `EditText`.

Comment: Can't you just put an if statement in your onClickListener?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check it yourseft, such as:

```
final EditText editText = ...; // your edit 

// check in your onClickListener
if (editText.getText().toString().isEmpty){ // Check if your EditText is 

}else{ // If your EditTexit is not null

}
```

Please, search google before asking any question!

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code,

suppose you have a EditText  txtNum1 & txtNum2 , so onClickListener() method you can write following condition

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
     if ( v == cmdCalculate )
     {
           if (  !txtNum1.getText().equals("") && !txtNum2.getText().equals("") )
           {
              // your calculation code
           }
           else
           {
             // post error msg code
           }
     }
}
```